# When did scriptio continua and interpuncts give way to spaces between words in Latin?

Tags: language-evolution, punctuation

From [this overview of punctuation in Classical Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/33/12), I understand that word spacing as we know it didn't really exist at that time: either an [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Latin) was used to separate words,  [or there was no word break at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptio_continua).

What do we know about the origins of word spacing (with an actual space) in Latin?   When did it become standard practice?  Did it do so on a particular medium first, or in a particular geographical area, perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roland Hinterhölzl (2009) *Information Structure and Language Change* p. 177 ([via Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=GbbN60KWOSoC&pg=PA177)):

> Roman scribes would usually operate by "copying texts in *scriptio continua* – that is, without separating words or indicating any pauses within a major section of text (Parkes 1993: 10). Separation by spaces ﬁrst appears in the Insular area (see Saenger 1997: 84-99). It is then used in the Carolingian period (see Müller 1964: 35, Bischoff 1986: 229, Saenger 1990); Parkes (1993: 31) discusses several cases in which Carolingian scribes copying older manuscripts introduced separation. However, spaces were not yet used in a consequent manner (see Saenger 1997: 100): in Carolingian minuscule manuscripts "space was present, but not consistently between every word" (Saenger 1997: 32). Saenger (I997: 32) refers to this kind of separation as "aerated script" (as opposed to "word separation" proper). In central and southern Germany "scribes, after the mid-ninth century, began to write Latin in intensely aerated script, sometimes approaching separation, and began to develop modes for writing the vernacular that were clearly stimulated by Anglo-Saxon models." (Saenger 1997: 102). It is notable that "only at the Abbey of Saint Gall, one of the larger Continental colonies of Irish and Anglo-Saxon monks, did the evolution of text format go so far as to continue consistent emulation of Insular word separation." (Saenger 1997: 103). The *Vocabularius Sancti Galli*, a Latin-Old High German dictionary, provides an early example of Continental word separation (see Saenger 1997: 103).

A whole book on the topic (with a surprising twist) is the one repeatedly cited above, [Paul Saenger (1997) *Space Between Words: The Origins of Silent Reading*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080474016X).