# What is the name of the separator dots between the words?

Tags: contemporary-latin, inscription, punctuation

Consider the following photo of the Westminster Cathedral:

[image: An inscription on Westminster Cathedral]

What are those separator-dots called? I see them on many inscriptions. Why is it there?

Answer (score 13):

It is called the [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct).

Empty space to separate words as we do now is not a universal phenomenon.
Just as well the Romans might ask why we leave space between words instead of putting a dot in between or spelling all the words together.

The dots mark word boundaries, but I am not sure if they are added more for legibility or similarity to ancient inscriptions.
Following ancient conventions does give a certain prestigious feel to an inscription.

In ancient Rome one would either separate words by an interpunct or not at all.
See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/222/79) for the development of word spacing.

Comment: Interestingly, most word processors for Roman-alphabet languages have a setting letting you see whitespace as symbols, and interpuncts are typically used for spaces.