# Why didn't readers prefer spacing to scriptio continua before 600 A.D.?

Tags: language-evolution

Naomi Baron. [*Words Onscreen: The Fate of Reading in a Digital World* (1 edn 2015)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199315760). Top of p. 21.

> [image]

I'm assuming that even in one's L1, “spaced words make it easier to decode in your head”.

Why wasn’t *scriptio continua* popularized or standardized earlier? I just can't fathom how nobody became aware of the godsend of spacing words before 600 A.D.!

Or did they suffer in silence all along before A.D. 600?

Comment: Most technologies gradually change, as new ways of doing things are invented, and it becomes hard to understand how people managed before. Writing is one of our oldest technologies.

Comment: I answered a question very like yours here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/why-did-roman-authors-never-feel-a-need-for-word-spacing/2685#2685

Comment: Modern Chinese still lacks spaces between words.