# Did the Romans have a "question mark"?

Tags: classical-latin, orthography, punctuation

Were questions in written classical Latin ever indicated by anything other than the meanings of the words<sup>1</sup> and the context?
That is, was there a "question mark"?
Here a "question mark" can mean some form of punctuation, but it could be any kind of signal.
For a silly example, one could indicate a question by increasing the size of letters towards the end of the question.
I am looking for non-verbal signals used in writing.

I read the question ["What punctuation was used in Classical Latin?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/33/79) and I know the modern question mark is younger.
I am under the impression that a question would normally not be marked in any way, but was this always the case?

---

<sup>1</sup>
This excludes question words like *quare*, *quis*, *num*, and *-ne*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [scholars](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/syriac-double-dot-worlds-earliest-question-mark/), the earliest written sign ever argued to play the role of an interrogation mark comes from a VI century Syriac manuscript, and passed later into Latin.

My intuition is that, in this case too, *necessity is the mother of invention*. Especially in antiquity, it is not very likely that a mark for which there was no special need made it into mainstream Latin.

For yes/no questions Latin regularly adds particles (e.g. *-ne*, *num*), and open questions usually require relatives (*quid*, *quando*, *cur*). Even word order change in some. There is no ambiguity in such questions, and hence no need to distinguish any further.

It is hard to tell whether Romans used a different intonation for questions. (Judging from Romance languages, it seems likely, though.) If they did, maybe it was possible to word a question just as an affirmative sentence, but then again, it was easier to re-word the sentence in written.